# Vertex Factor for Electron-Neutron Interaction Feynman Diagram

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I am pretty new to QED and Quantum field theory. I am currently learning Feynman Diagrams and I was interested in electron-neutron scattering, $e^-N -> e^-N $ specifically in vertex factors. In Griffiths, Introduction to Elementary Particles (2nd edition) for QED coupling constant he gives a general form for any 1/2 spin : g<sub>e</sub> = -*q*$\sqrt{4 \pi/\hbar c}$ for . Where he states *q* to be the charge of the particle.

Would that still apply to neutron as it has 0 charge? because it would just equate the  g<sub>e</sub> to 0 resulting in vertex factor :  ig<sub>e</sub> $\gamma$<sup>$\mu$</sup> to 0.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would consider a neutron as a single particle then indeed it does not interact via electromagnetism with the electron. However, we know that the neutron is made up of quarks and gluons and so a more correct way is to describe the interaction via a distribution functions of these quarks and gluons forming the neutron. This is called a [parton distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_(particle_physics)).